# structure of solvable linear algebraic group

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-groups

Im having a misunderstanding regarding the following theorem, taken for T.A springer's linear algebraic groups.

I should add that in the context of the theorem G is solvable and conncted.
[image]

My question is thus.
Why doesn't claim (iv) imply G is a direct product of T and G<sub>u</sub>?

I know G<sub>u</sub> is normal, and since G=TG<sub>u</sub>,  if x is an element of T all its conjugates are of the form, tu ,where t is in T and u in G<sub>u</sub> but x is semisimple and so u must be the identity element and thus all conjugates of x are in T and T is normal.

What is the flaw with this argument? i know i must be misunderstanding something.

Comment: Every connected solvable
subgroup G is isomorphic to a *semidirect* product $T\ltimes G_u$. Why should it be a direct product?

Comment: by my argument above T should be normal and of triviall intersection with Gu, shouldn't that imply a direct product?

Comment: This is then a semidirect product. For direct product, both factors should be normal, which isn't true.

Comment: that is exactly my question why isnt T normal by the above argument?

Comment: Take the standard example of upper-triangular matrices for $G$ to see that it is not true.

Comment: i see the problem now. i misunderstood the uniqueness of decomposition into semi-simple and unipotent part of a matrix. the decomposition is unique only in the case commuting semisimple and unipotnent components

Comment: Yes, exactly. We see this already with upper-triangular matrices of small size.